# How can we get the coordinates of the current text input globally

Tags: cocoa

How is it possible to get the coordinates of the current text input globally?
I am familiar with Quartz Event Taps and NSEvent API for monitoring events, but I have not yet found a way to figure out where on the screen text input is occurring.
Is there an API I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the Accessibility API.

Take a look at `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(... kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute ...)`

Once you have the focused element, you can grab screen coordinates from it.

Comment: The author of Dash actually shared example code with me on how to do this. but in a very basic way, what you post is correct.